# Sharing a common dll/pyd dependencies for several exe in Python

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, dll, py2exe

I am successfully using `py2exe` to produce a Windows binary distribution of several independant Python scripts (using standard Python27.dll + PyQt pyd files + Matplotlib pyd files) producing an executable for each one (`app1.exe`, `app2.exe`, ...).

Each of these executables work as expected if kept in the same directory as their dynamic dependencies (**these dependencies are exactly the same**)

I tried to create a common directory, say `CommonDynamicLibrariesPython` , which contains all these dll/pyd dependencies, then place each application in a different location and attempt to run it through a batch file after I set the path system variable locally to include the dll/pyd, using something like:

```
:: run_app1.bat placed in c:\dir_app1

set PYTHONDLL=my_path_to_CommonDynamicLibrariesPython
set PATH=%PYTHONDLL%;%PATH%
start /B app1.exe
```

Alternately I tried also changing `PYTHONPATH` from the batch and from the python script itself, but no luck.

Can anyone tell me why isn't this possible ?

**In other words, is it possible to run a python executable produced by `py2exe` when placed outside its original `dist` folder, *without* using shortcuts, but using a batch file**

Comment: check [regsrv32](http://ss64.com/nt/regsvr32.html) , Or use shortcuts to your exes with the dlls in the same directory.Or if you want to call them from bat file use `call c:\python_apps\app1.exe ...` where the dll's are in the same directory as the appp.

Comment: Reading the link you sent, I understand that regsrv32 installs the dlls/pyds in system32. But I really want to understand why isn't it sufficient to manipulate either of `PATH` or `PYTHONPATH` ? assuming that I don't prefer touching `system32` ...

Comment: Generally modifying `PATH` should work. The loader searches `PATH` for DLL dependencies. There may be a specific reason why it's not working in your case, but you'll have to provide more information. Include the list of DLLs that you've moved to a common directory and the exact error message that you're getting. It would also help if you could run the executable in WinDbg with loader snaps enabled for it via gflags.exe.